# WPF Changing Controls within a data template?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

so now that I can access controls hidden within nested datatemplates, it seems that I cannot change their values. For instance I have the code (granted to me graciously by a Stack overflow member)

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="frontTemplate" >
        <StackPanel x:Name="noWork">
            <Image Source="Images/1.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="72" Height="96" x:Name="FrontFace"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="flipItemTemplate">
        <Grid Width="200" Height="200">

            <Border x:Name="frontHost" Background="Transparent">
                <ContentPresenter Name="contentPresenter"  Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource frontTemplate}" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

And although I can get TO the image in that second template (frontFace) I can't get the source to change. I can get a new bitmap, and load it without error, but the image does not change. If I put an image control in the XAML outside of the datatemplate and load it with my bitmap code there, it works fine. This leads me to believe that the template can't redraw itself after its been applied... BUT I can't get access to its internal elements until its been applied... so how in the heck do I dynamically set up elements in a template before its been applied?

Answer (score 0):

The template *duplicates* its content. You are accessing the `Image` element of your template, not the one instanciated in the content presenter.

Comment: So how would I set the content of the template BEFORE it gets duplicated/rendered ? that's my problem.. chicken and egg sort of deal. but as far as I know, you can't get access to the element in the template before its applied because the visual tree hasn't been created yet, right?

Comment: Bind the `Source` of your `Image` element to a property of the data object. The property must be an `ImageSource` or convertible to an `ImageSource` by a converter.

Comment: And that way on load I can manipulate the data object, which, since its bound, will manipulate the elements in the template - OK I'll give that a shot...

Comment: Hmm even binding is unsuccessful. Again with the above XAML, say I have this class:

Comment: GRR.. can't format in comments! so public class WPFISHard { public string MyName {get; set;} }    in my XAML I add this to the window tag Name="MyControl" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=InstOfWPFISHard}" and in my image tag I have Source="{Binding Path=MyName}"                          Still Nothing